# Why is the onEdit function not triggered in my google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have seen some people ask questions about this, but I can't seem to find an answer yet.

I created a Google Sheet with a Google Script by going to `Extra->Script Editor`.

Now in the script, I created a function called `onSheetUpdate`:

```
function onSheetUpdate(e){

  console.log("test");
  console.log(e);

}
```

At first, I configured the `Change` event but this did not give me the Event object I needed so I changed it to the `Edit` event.

[image]

Sorry for the Dutch!

The `Change` event worked perfectly and I got output inside the stackdriver log. But the `Edit` event is not working. Why is it not working?

Comment: If my understanding of your situation is correct, when it sees the document at [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onchange) and [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onedit), onChange() and onEdit() are ``Specifies a trigger that will fire when the spreadsheet's content or structure is changed.`` and ``Specifies a trigger that will fire when the spreadsheet is edited.``, respectively.

Comment: So as the test, when you try onChange(), please add a row and check the log. When you try onEdit(), please modify the cell value and check the log.

Comment: I'm really sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: Haha, don't worry, thanks for the fast response!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out that the solution is even easier than I could imagine.

Just create a function with this signature `OnEdit(e)` and it will fire on every change. **You don't even need to create one** in the weird little menu.

Just use this code:

```
function onEdit(e){
  console.log(e);
}
```

**Don't** register one:
[image]

And then when you spin up the Stack Driver logging:

[image]

You will see that it works:

[image]

Note that I use `console.log()` and I sometimes need to tweak the filters a little.

Comment: Note that there are significant differences between simple triggers (those with a reserved function name like `onEdit` or `onOpen`) and installed triggers (created with that menu or `ScriptApp.createTrigger`). It is advisable to know this difference well.